# Touchscreen LS-7 Windows IOT issues

Tags: touchscreen, windows-iot

I bought this touchscreen for my Pi. Screen works perfectly but the touch controller does have some problems. It is recognized by my Pi as Touch, at least it says it in the connected devices scection. Now here comes the problem when I use the touch, furthermore when i click for the first time it recognizes my action and it works but thats it, after 1 action the Touch doesnt work anymore even though the LED on my Touch-controller still lights up when I touch the screen.

So all in all, my problem is that I can only touch once, afterwards it doesnt work anymore. Anyone has a solution for that or maybe any universal dirvers?

Comment: Power supply!  You need more juice!

Comment: I have 2000 mA power Supply, that should be enough, right?

Comment: Should be.. maybe its not. What power supply is, and how do you have everything connected. Can you post a pic of the connection and how everything is powered up.

Comment: I am at work right now, but i can tell u for now: RasPi - micro USB 5V 2000mA, Mouse - USB, Touch Controller - USB, Display -HDMI and has its own power supply

Comment: It should be adequate, though you could try with a shorter USB cable since long or lower quality USB cables sap juice quite quickly. You can also try measuring the power output of course, given you have the tools for it.

Comment: Yea.. some USB cables have reaaaaaaly thin wires, that is a good point by Havnar. But if you everything connected to the PI USB... then there could be your problem. You may need a HUB. We dont know, cause what screen model you got? How much power does it take, etc etc

Comment: The thing is this display is made for RasPis u can use it on the RasPi 1 without any issues and without a HUB. Here is a link to it, it's in German though, maybe u could use google translator: http://www.pollin.de/shop/dt/NTMwOTc4OTk-/Bauelemente_Bauteile/Aktive_Bauelemente/Displays/7_17_78_cm_Display_Set_mit_Touchscreen_LS_7T_HDMI_DVI_VGA_CVBS.html

Comment: It must be a Windows driver problem. Did you manage to get this working with any new version of IoT? HID driver issues, defiantly report as bug to MS so they can sort it out asap. You should be able to test in on a Normal Windows computer too without any drivers as a second display on HDMI

Comment: On Windows 10 everyxhting works just fine, on IOT still same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the latest update LS-7T is now supported by Windows IOT.